# Retrieving json in javascript function with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I would like to read json value.
The way that I am writing the code is as shown in below.
where x will be the $movieID.

```
<script>
     function bookBTN(x) {
        <?php $url = 'http://movie.com/movieOne?seatNum=' . x;
         $jsonURL = file_get_contents($url);
         $obj = json_decode($jsonURL,true); 
            foreach($obj as $data)
            {
             $res = $data['avail'];
            }
           if ($res == "yes"){
             echo "alert ('SUCESS');";
           }
           else
           {
             echo "alert ('FAIL');";

           }


        ?>

     }
</script>
```

However, when I tried to click on the button, it doesn't pop up the alert box.
If I removed the json retriever inside the function, the alert box will then be working. Why is that so and how can I solve the problem?

data:

```
{"avail":"yes"}
```

Comment: `$url = 'http://movie.com/movieOne?seatNum=' + x;` change `+` to `.`

Comment: Why you need to use PHP for that? Why not use `$.get()`/`$.post()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the PHP works (although depending how it treats `x` as a literal, it might not) then the output of this on your page will be either `<script>function bookBTN(x) { alert('SUCESS')';}</script>` or `<script>function bookBTN(x) { alert('FAIL')';}</script>`. I doubt that is what you intended. You can't interchange `x` between the scripts like this.

PHP runs on the server, and JavaScript runs on the browser, in totally separate contexts. PHP runs to create the page content, which may include some HTML, CSS, JS etc. The output of the PHP script is a page which is then sent to the browser on the client machine, to be displayed and interacted with. This means you can use PHP to *generate* some static JS which then *runs later* when the page loads.

If you want some interactivity between JS and PHP after the page is loaded, you need to use AJAX calls to send data between the client and server in a manner that both understand.

However, for this particular simple example, it's likely you don't need any PHP at all, because, assuming this remove server supports CORS, you can simply call it directly from JavaScript using AJAX. Note that your PHP code also had a logical error with the foreach, because it would only ever match the last "data" value to see if it contained "yes", since that test was outside the loop.

This example uses jQuery syntax to perform the ajax GET request and loop through the data, but it's also possible to do both with vanilla JS.

EDIT: It's clear now that the remote server does not accept CORS requests. Therefore we need to use your PHP server as an intermediary. Your solution will therefore need to be in two parts. Also, the data structure returned by the function is not what was originally suggested by your PHP snippet:

1) Your existing web page, with the same code, but the ajax call changed to point at your own PHP server:

```
<script>
     function bookBTN(x) {
        alert("x = " + x); //you can use this for testing, and remove later
        $.getJSON('http://yourservername/movieOne.php?seatNum=' + x, function(data) { 
          if (data.avail == "yes") {
            alert("Success"); //note correct spelling of "success"
          }
          else { alert("Failure"); } //only if we didn't find anything
        });
     }
</script>
```

2) A PHP script on your server to act as the intermediary. For the sake of example I've called it movieOne.php, to reflect that it calls the movieOne URL on the remote server.

```
<?php
  $seatNum = $_GET["seatNum"]; //retrieve the seat number from the browser ajax request
  $url = 'http://movie.com/movieOne?seatNum=' . $seatNum;
  $result = file_get_contents($url); //make the request to the remote server
  echo $result; //echo the result directly back to the ajax call without processing it. If this doesn't return JSON already, then try using "json_encode($result);" instead
?>
```

Comment: Hi, do I have to define res? I don't get what it meant by car res = false and data.each(function(index,val)

Comment: `res` is the boolean which holds whether we have found the item you're searching for or not. So yes we have to give it an initial value of false, until we find something. `.each` is like doing a foreach loop. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: I tried the code that you wrote, but then on my end it doesn't work. The alert box didn't shows up.

Comment: ok, so you need to do some basic debugging. 1) are there any errors in your browser's console? 2) Did the "bookBtn" function actually run? (To test, add a line `alert("x = " + x);` at the start of the function, this will let us check the value of x as well). 3) If the function ran ok, did the ajax call succeed (check your browser's network tab and see if the call to movie.com return "200" status, or something else)?

Comment: P.S. I also noticed a small error in the script, please check it and use my updated version.

Comment: The function is running, as  alert("x = " + x) is working. However, I don't get where it doesn't shows whether it's sucessful or fail

Comment: in that case follow step 3 above to check what the result of the ajax call was. If the status is not 200, then please report the error that's given, and any extra errors within the response body.

Comment: I only able to see the current file directory that I'm in on the network tab

Comment: There's no entry like "movieOne?seatNum=1" in the network tab? Ensure you've got either the "All" or "XHR" option selected (in Chrome dev tools that would be, might be something else if you use another browser). And no errors or warnings in the console?

Comment: Im using firefox, there isn't any entry like what you've said.

Comment: There is an error saying movie.php:394 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at bookBTN (movie.php:394)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (VM295 movie.php:16)

Comment: I did tell you the script requires jQuery. That error means you need to include jQuery. If for any reason however you don't want to use jQuery we will have to re-write the script. I also previously asked you if there were any console errors and you said no, but clearly there were.

Comment: I was using firefox, it didn't show me any error. The error was only shown up when I used chrome to access to it. Currently, I have make the necessary changes regarding to the error. However, down with one of the error, which I think you did mention , which is the CORS.  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: ok. I was concerned about that possibility. Basically it means the remote server will not accept AJAX requests from web pages outside its own domain. In that case we will need to use your PHP server as an intermediary. I will write a new answer, bear with me.

Comment: Thanks so much for you help.

Comment: yes. I thought it was better to give it a meaningful name.

Comment: what was the value of "x" in the Javascript? If you do `var_dump($_GET);` as well at the start of the PHP it will show you if seatNum was passed as a parameter to movieOne.php as well.

Comment: as stated in the question, the x value is the $movieID

Comment: movie.php:398 Uncaught TypeError: data.each is not a function

Comment: no i meant what is the _actual real_ value that you were testing with? And was it passed through to the $_GET successfully? Anyway, looks like you've maybe moved past that stage.

Comment: movie.php:398 Uncaught TypeError: data.each is not a function
    at Object.success (movie.php:398)
    at Object.resolveWith (jquery.min.js:16)
    at v (jquery.min.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.min.js:16)

Comment: Sorry it should be `$.each(data, function(index, val) {`. have updated the answer again. That's assuming data is coming back as an actual object or array.

Comment: Can I check with you, how can I actually see what are the value that it's running through? I mean how do I throw out the result for this (val.avail == "yes")?

Comment: you can set breakpoints in code via the dev tools and then examine variable values. Or you could use the console to check values at different times (via the `console.log` command, e.g. putting `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` just after the `var res...` line would show you the full contents of the data variable so you can check the structure and whether it's JSON or a string, and contains the items you expect).

Comment: because I realise, the result than Im getting right, is showing "failure" instead of "success"

Comment: Without seeing the data that's returned from the ajax call, I can't tell you if that's a bug or not.

Comment: what do you need?

Comment: the data returned from the ajax call. i.e. the contents of the `data` variable. Which you can get by following my instructions above. Then we can look at the structure and see if the code is doing what it's supposed to. Based on your original example, it looks like we're expecting an array of objects, and if at least one of those objects has a property called "avail" where the value is set to "yes", then we report "success". If not, we report "failure". Is that what you want?

Comment: yes, there's one property called "avail" where value is "yes". If it run through and see that the particular seat shown is avail:"yes", then it will report success. Currently, the seat I have is "yes" , but it printed "failure" instead.

Comment: ok so show me the data and we can start to see where we're going wrong...Edit it into the question, as it's likely to be hard to read in comments.

Comment: not too sure if it's what you're looking for.. Have edited the question

Comment: yep that's it. That's the data. Which shows it's not an array at all, as the original code suggested, but just a single object with one property. So the code can be made much simpler.

Comment: How can I go about doing it?

Comment: see my latest edit. I think you ought to take some sort of tutorial in how to traverse JS / JSON objects (they are the same thing), it will make your life a lot easier if you carry on doing this sort of coding, and these sorts of problems will become a lot simpler to solve.

Comment: for the php script, can I write it as a function (i.e function seatNum(){}) , then call it from the url link?

Comment: if you like, yes. Something like `<?php $seatNum = $_GET["seatNum"]; getSeatNum($seatNum);`. Then the function would be `function getSeatNum($seatNum) {` and include the rest of the code in my answer.

Comment: the url is the same?

Comment: the URL has to be the name of the PHP file (unless you employ Apache rewrite rules). Like I explained in the answer, you can't call a PHP function directly from JS, you have to call something which can respond to a HTTP request. A function on its own cannot do that, it has to be within a script that can be served by Apache, and it's the thing which Apache serves that you have to reference in the ajax call.

Comment: Anyway, does it work now? If so, please mark the answer as accepted - thanks. We are getting beyond the scope of the question now.

Comment: yes, but it's probably best if you ask a new question and make clear what exactly you want to achieve and what you've tried already. If you link to the new question here I'll take a look

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205445/how-to-call-a-function-in-the-url-php

Answer (score 0):

You can't use JS and PHP as same level functions. PHP will be executed before any JS will ever start. So your code will throw `Undefined constant x`, because `x` in JS is not same as `x` in PHP, plus variables in PHP has to start with `$x`.

---

For your function you do not need PHP. Use jQuery Ajax

```
 function bookBTN(x) {
     $.ajax({
         url: 'http://movie.com/movieOne?seatNum='+x,
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function (obj) {
             var found = false;

             obj.each(function (i, res) {
                 if (res.avail == 'yes') {
                     alert('SUCCESS');
                     found = true;

                     return false;
                 }
             });

             if (!found) {
                 alert('FAIL');
             }
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: I tried, but the button still doesn't seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

You might want to call the url as jsonp datatype because it looks like it will call a url from a different domain.
Note that $.ajax is a jquery function.

---

```js
$.ajax({
 url: "http://movie.com/movieOne?seatNum=" + x,
 jsonp: "callback",
 dataType: "jsonp",
 data: {query: "foo"},
 success: function (response) {
  // do whatever you want with the response data
 }
});
```