# How to call a function in the URL (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php

Currently I have this code as shown below.
Whereby, when I click on the button, it will show either success or fail.
I have another php script on another webpage to call from it.

Currently I call the php script, using the php file name. I would like to check is there a way for me to call the php file using a function in the url?
The reason is because, in the php script, I would have several functions to call from. I do not want to create multiple php file.

below is my code.

```
<script>
     function bookBTN(x) {
       $.getJSON('http://localhost/movieOne.php?method=getSeatNum1&seatNum=' + x, function(data) { 
          if (data.avail == "yes") {
            alert("Success"); 
          }
          else { alert("Failure"); } 
        });
     }
</script>

    <script>
     function viewBTN(x) {
       $.getJSON('http://localhost/movieOne.php?method=getSeatNum2&seatNum=' + x, function(data) { 
          if (data.avail == "yes") {
            alert("Success"); 
          }
          else { alert("Failure"); } 
        });
     }
</script>
```

movieOne.php

```
  <?php
    $seatNum= $_GET["seatNum"]; 
    getSeatNum1($seatNum);
    function getSeatNum1($seatNum) {
      $seatNum = $_GET["seatNum"]; 
      $url = 'http://movie.com/movieOne?seatNum=' . $seatNum;
      $result = file_get_contents($url); 
      echo $result; 
    ?>

 <?php
    $seatNum= $_GET["seatNum"]; 
    getSeatNum2($seatNum);
    function getSeatNum2($seatNum) {
      $seatNum = $_GET["seatNum"]; 
      $url = 'http://movie.com/movieOne?seatNum=' . $seatNum;
      $result = file_get_contents($url); 
      echo $result; 
    ?>
```

When I only run `http://localhost/movieOne.php?method=getSeatNum1&seatNum=' + x` and having only 1 php function inside movieOne.php , it works fine.

When I run `http://localhost/movieOne.php?method=getSeatNum1&seatNum=' + x`and `http://localhost/movieOne.php?method=getSeatNum2&seatNum=' + x` ,  having only 1 php function inside movieOne.php , it works fine too.

However when I run `http://localhost/movieOne.php?method=getSeatNum1&seatNum=' + x`and `http://localhost/movieOne.php?method=getSeatNum2&seatNum=' + x` , and have 2 different function (as the code above), the button doesn't work.

Comment: A way to do this is also pass another GET variable called something like `method`, which tells your PHP script which function to use. You would then in your PHP first check the `method` property and call a particular function based upon that value. E.g. `$.getJSON('.../movieOne.php?method=getSeatNum&seatNum=' + x)`, and in your PHP you only execute the `getSeatNum` if the method matched.

Comment: first check $seatNum= $_GET["seatNum"];  then use if else..... if searNum is what u want or end ur script

Comment: what exactly would you like the URL to look like, ideally? Give an example of the desired URL.

Comment: I got no ideal URL. what varbrad did is okay. But when i have 2 function in the same page (movieOne.php), it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I've edited my question

Comment: you need an if statement to decide which function to run based on the value of `$_GET["method"]`. Otherwise it'll run them both. You should also whitelist the allowed functions to avoid someone trying to execute any function that might in your page, or in an include to that page, where you might not want them to execute that function directly (could cause security issues, for instance). And you don't need to do `$seatNum= $_GET["seatNum"]; ` twice. Once at the start of the script is enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call function from url like codeigniter do, i have an example for you

URL example: `http://localhost/jastip/ajax/request.php/get_orders`

```
(function () {
    $url_function = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $function_name = get_defined_functions()['user'];    

    if (in_array($url_function[4], $function_name)) {
        $index = array_search($url_function[4], $function_name);
        $dynamic_fun = $function_name[$index];
        $dynamic_fun();
    } else {
        var_dump("Page not found");
        die;
    }
})();    

function get_orders()
{
    echo "get orders";
}    

function get_something()
{
    echo "get something";
}
```